# ¿Sacar el promedio en un Array en C?

Tags: array, c

Tengo este código que saca el valor mayor y menor de un array de 30 números en C (los cuales funcionan bien), el problema viene donde me piden que tengo que sacar el promedio de los elementos del array donde hago primero la suma de todos los elementos y ya después solo utilizo esa variable y la divido entre 30 ,pero en la ejecución me devuelve el print que el valor del promedio es 0)

soy aprendiz básico del lenguaje así que me gustaría saber donde esta el error

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){

    int vector[30];
    int i;


    for (i=0; i<30; i++){
        printf( "ingrese 30 numeros enteros. Numero %d\n", i+1);
        scanf("%d", &vector[i]);
    }
    int mayor,menor;
    mayor=vector[0];
    menor= vector[0];
    float promedio;
    int total;

    for (i=0; i<30; i++){
        if (vector[i]> mayor){
            mayor=vector[i];
        }
    }
    printf("El mayor es %d\n", mayor);

    for (i=1; i<30; i++){
        if (vector[i]< menor){
            menor=vector[i];
        }
    }
    printf("El menor es %d\n", menor);
    for (i=0; i<30; i++){
    total+=vector[i];
        promedio= total/30;
    }
    printf("El Promedio es:%d\n",promedio);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Actualizacion: error sencillo que logre encontrar, en el printf del final debi poner %f en vez de %d, RESUELTO!

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español! Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Aparte de eso, que deberia ir como respuesta si lo amerita, calcular el promerio en cada vuelta no tiene mucho sentido, mejor calcularlo una sola vez cuando termines el for.

Comment: Además de lo que comentas sobre el `printf`, haz `promedio= total/30.0;` y no `promedio= total/30;` o perderás la parte decimal. Por otro lado calcula promedio fuera del ciclo como comenta gbianchi y no en cada iteración y podrías hacerlo todo en un solo ciclo y no en tres. Por último, es buena idea siempre inicializar cualquier variable `int total = 0;`...

Answer (score 1):

Siguiendo los comentarios expuestos esta deberia ser tu solucion:

```c
    for (i=0; i<30; i++){
        total+=vector[i];    
    }

    promedio= total/30.0;
    printf("El Promedio es:%f\n",promedio);
```

La division por 30 devuelve un entero con lo que pierdes los decimales. Necesitas hacerlo por 30.0 para que asi haga division de numeros reales. Para nosotros 30.0 = 30 pero para la maquina no.
Y has de hacer la division fuera del bucle, porque si la haces dentro realmente no estas calculando el promedio.

Finalmente, como te han comentado, no necesitas hacer 3 bucles. En el primero puedes introducir los dos bloques if y la suma del promedio. El resultado seria tal que asi:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){

    int vector[30];
    int i;


    for (i=0; i<30; i++){
        printf( "ingrese 30 numeros enteros. Numero %d\n", i+1);
        scanf("%d", &vector[i]);
    }
    int mayor,menor;
    mayor=vector[0];
    menor= vector[0];
    float promedio;
    int total;

    for (i=0; i<30; i++){
        if (vector[i]> mayor){
            mayor=vector[i];
        }

        if (vector[i]< menor){
            menor=vector[i];
        }

        total+=vector[i];
    }
    printf("El mayor es %d\n", mayor);
    printf("El menor es %d\n", menor);

    promedio = total/30.0;
    printf("El Promedio es:%f\n",promedio);

    return 1;
}
```

Comment: Siguiendo los comentarios expuestos, [SVGA98 ya había resuelto su problema](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/287082/sacar-el-promedio-en-un-array-en-c#comment527139_287082).

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster Ese comentario no soluciona el problema ya que aunque ayuda a imprimir el valor de la variable promedio, el motivo por el que esta imprimiendo 0 es porque el resultado es 0.xxxxxx ya que esta dividiendo el promedio en cada iteracion del bucle.

Comment: Tienes razón **pero** si SVGA98 afirma que ha resuelto su problema ¿Quiénes somos nosotros para dudarlo?

Comment: Oh! No me fije que son el mismo usuario. Mil perdones pues. Pregunta de novato: No deberia haberse publicado entonces como respuesta?

Comment: El propio usuario afirma que es un error en su código así que la respuesta puede dar es "*Lo siento, me equivoqué escribiendo esto*" lo cuál aporta poco al sitio, por eso la pregunta ha sido reportada como "*Error tipográfico*" (si te fijas, tiene dos reportes de cierre).

Comment: No puedo ver si tiene reportes (o no se donde se ve eso). Gracias igualmente por la info :)